# Gitlab tells me that the Connection is refused

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

After fixing some space problems I stumble into the next issue.
I try to reinstall GitLab on my Docker machine:

```
docker run --detach --hostname psmonster  
 --env GITLAB_OMNIBUS_CONFIG="external_url 'http://psmonster:20080/'; gitlab_rails['lfs_enabled'] = true;"  
 --publish 20443:443
 --publish 20080:80 
 --publish 20022:22 
 --name gitlab_2
 --restart always   
 --volume /srv/gitlab/config:/etc/gitlab
 --volume /srv/gitlab/logs:/var/log/gitlab
 --volume /srv/gitlab/data:/var/opt/gitlab 
 gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest

docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                     COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS                   PORTS                                                                  NAMES
b374db326f2a        gitlab/gitlab-ce:latest   "/assets/wrapper"   3 minutes ago       Up 3 minutes (healthy)   0.0.0.0:20022->22/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20080->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:20443->443/tcp   gitlab
```

So I thought that when I now use my browser to get the UI (as I've done in the past), I will get it on psmoster:20080. But my browser is telling me "ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED".

So I tried to curl direct on the machine. Same result "curl: (7) Failed to connect to psmonster port 20080: Connection refused".

So I jump directly into the container. "docker exec -it gitlab bash"

```
root@psmonster:/# curl http://localhost:80
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 80: Connection refused
```

So I don't understand my mistake?

I also set this to port 20080, a simple nignx instance, and this was working fine. So it isn't a firewall issue or something.

Comment: looks like while the container is running, gitlab-ce isn't.  Check the logs

Comment: That's right. The logs are telling me "Every thing is nice"

Comment: I found out that when I do 20080:20080 I can reach the UI.

Comment: ports under 1024 aren't allowed for listening on many Linux variants except for root...maybe this is the cause of the problem?